# How to build a reverse order unique index per group in R

Tags: r, dplyr

My data looks like this.

```
#My data
df <- structure(list(G1 = c("k", "i", "g", "r", "d", "l", "q", "q", 
"g", "g", "u", "c", "q", "m", "x"), Val = c(-0.451975472583735, 
-0.19872979175927, -0.679638598629673, 0.576615598731837, -1.37035635941051, 
-1.1166732375321, 0.386801159348088, -0.785735341658561, 0.557918504391552, 
-0.0222346091056282, -0.324145474459458, 0.167768244637546, -0.150116509879256, 
0.491114845804244, 0.598188306361648)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

I am looking for a way to identify each group with an unique value but instead of going from 1 to number of groups, I would like the first group start with n groups and so on until last group is identified by one. My ideal output would be:

```
   G1         Val Group
1   c  0.16776824    11
2   d -1.37035636    10
3   g -0.67963860     9
4   g  0.55791850     9
5   g -0.02223461     9
6   i -0.19872979     8
7   k -0.45197547     7
8   l -1.11667324     6
9   m  0.49111485     5
10  q  0.38680116     4
11  q -0.78573534     4
12  q -0.15011651     4
13  r  0.57661560     3
14  u -0.32414547     2
15  x  0.59818831     1
```

Answer (score 4):

An option is to convert the 'G1' to a `factor` class with `levels` specified in as `rev`erse of `unique` elements of 'G1' and then coerce it to `integer` with `as.integer`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(Group2 = as.integer(factor(G1, levels = rev(unique(G1)))))
```

-output

```
#    G1         Val Group Group2
#1   c  0.16776824    11     11
#2   d -1.37035636    10     10
#3   g -0.67963860     9      9
#4   g  0.55791850     9      9
#5   g -0.02223461     9      9
#6   i -0.19872979     8      8
#7   k -0.45197547     7      7
#8   l -1.11667324     6      6
#9   m  0.49111485     5      5
#10  q  0.38680116     4      4
#11  q -0.78573534     4      4
#12  q -0.15011651     4      4
#13  r  0.57661560     3      3
#14  u -0.32414547     2      2
#15  x  0.59818831     1      1
```

---

Or using `match`, it is straightforward, to return the position by matching the 'G1' with `rev`erse`of`unique` elements of 'G1'

```
df %>%
  mutate(Group2 = match(G1, rev(unique(G1))))
```

-output

```
#     G1         Val Group Group2
#1   c  0.16776824    11     11
#2   d -1.37035636    10     10
#3   g -0.67963860     9      9
#4   g  0.55791850     9      9
#5   g -0.02223461     9      9
#6   i -0.19872979     8      8
#7   k -0.45197547     7      7
#8   l -1.11667324     6      6
#9   m  0.49111485     5      5
#10  q  0.38680116     4      4
#11  q -0.78573534     4      4
#12  q -0.15011651     4      4
#13  r  0.57661560     3      3
#14  u -0.32414547     2      2
#15  x  0.59818831     1      1
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df$Group <-  with(df, match(G1, rev(unique(G1))))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(G1 = c("c", "d", "g", "g", "g", "i", "k", "l", 
"m", "q", "q", "q", "r", "u", "x"), Val = c(0.16776824, -1.37035636, 
-0.6796386, 0.5579185, -0.02223461, -0.19872979, -0.45197547, 
-1.11667324, 0.49111485, 0.38680116, -0.78573534, -0.15011651, 
0.5766156, -0.32414547, 0.59818831), Group = c(11L, 10L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15"))
```

Comment: @DarkShadow To understand the function, you can always check the documentation with `?match` `?rev`, `?unique`.  Thank you

Comment: @DarkShadow please notice that an SO answer is *not* the place for detailed explanations of used functions like `factor` and `as.integer` - there is the documentation for that purpose.